# Real-time Reporting via Web Services (PowerPivot Futures)

Tags: web-services, reporting, powerpivot

I apologize in advance as this question is quite vague.

About a month ago, I stumbled across a blog post featuring some information about a project within Microsoft Research relating to the following:

> Creating custom reports online and being able to export them into Excel and PowerPoint. The reports contain the necessary information to stream live data from the services they are connected to.

I'm not sure if the writer said it's from the PowerPivot team, but it was something along the lines of the future of custom reporting with real-time data.

He mentioned the project "codename", but for the life of me I can't remember it. Does anyone happen to know anything about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that Project Crescent is what you're looking for:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlrsteamblog/archive/2010/11/09/a-glimpse-at-project-crescent.aspx